# I18n Show text with link inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, public-activity

I'd like to a text that looks like:

> You created a new [User](http://google.com)

But what i get is just a plain text:

```
You crated a new <a href="/link/to/user">User</a>
```

I'm using public_activity gem to track changes inside my app.

Here is my view:

```
#app/views/activities/index.html.slim

.panel.panel-default
  .list-group
    - @activities.each do |activity|
    .list-group-item
      = render_activity(activity)
      .pull-right
        = activity.created_at
```

and how i use the activies:

```
= t '.log', trackable_name: link_to("User", root_path)

log: 'You created a new %{trackable_name}'
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Helpers output is HTML-escaped by default. To prevent this, you can use `html_safe`: `= t('.log', trackable_name: link_to('User', root_path)).html_safe`.

Comment: this didn't work, but i managed to make it work changing "log:" to "log_html:". Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= raw(t('.log', trackable_name: link_to("User", root_path)))
```